# How to add widgets to a rule both from kv file and py file in the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Is there a way so that I can add widgets to a specific rule in kivy both from kivy file and python file at the same time?

.kv

```
<A>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        id: someID
        Button:
            text:"some text"
            on_press: root.do_some_stuff()
<RootWidget>:
    A:
        name: "rule"
```

.py

```
class A(Screen):
    def do_some_stuff(self):
        print("I was told to do some stuff")

class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()
```

How can I add another label to GridLayout widget from the class A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `id` that you have specified in the `kv`:

```
class A(Screen):
    def do_some_stuff(self):
        self.ids.someID.add_widget(Label(text="I was told to do some stuff"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer really helped!